# Asp web service should stop execution when client ends its timeout wait period

Tags: c#, web-services

If my client application times out its web service method wait period(timeout period) then my service method should also stop its working.

This is required to achieve because client application has other things to execute based on result of web service.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills ,See my webservice method Abc() writes data 'B' in server db and if my php client gets such acknw then it too write data 'B' in its client db. But if anyhow this call fails then client revert its data back to 'A'.
 Now if client is calling service method with 5 sec timeout period and webservice took it more than that timeout period but completed its task; then client is rollbacking its data to 'A'. But webservice is running behind and makes its data to 'B'. so here client and server data not staying in sync.
So how can i control this by rollbacking webservice method too. thanks.

Comment: Does the server know what the client's timeout period is?